# changing background color of element with repeated clicks on a single button

Tags: javascript, button, logic

```
function myfunction3() {
  var m = Math.random() * 10 + 1;
  if (m < 2.5) {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else if (m < 5) {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (m < 7.5) {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}
```

Hello I am a new learner in javascript and I am creating a practice website. What I wish to do is change the background color of the element(whose id is "bg") one by one on repeated clicks of a single button. I have called the same function in my HTML file (onclick="myfunction3( )"). So far I could only think of this logic but this is not the most efficient way to do it. Please help me on how to do it in a better way? Or an online resource from where I can learn myself is also good.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this 'isn't the most efficient way to do it'? What is it that is worrying you about the code?

Comment: @AHaworth I am new to this so I assumed that the code was not that efficient as it was my first try. also, the problem is that, if I call the function one time and the color is red(say) and what if I call the function again and it is still generates a value less than 2.5  and the result will be red again. I want to avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using document.getElementById again and again would certainly slow down your program, but not nearly enough to be noticable. You could also remove the operation on the random value, and make the conditions based on its value between 0 and 1 instead of 1 to 10. Here's my approach to the optimization:

```js
bg_element = document.getElementById("bg");

function myfunction3() {
    var m = Math.random();
    if (m < 0.25) {
        bg_element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else if (m < 0.5) {
        bg_element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    } else if (m < 0.75) {
        bg_element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        bg_element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

## Super Important Caveat

While I appreciate you trying to learn about optimizations this early, it's a rabbit hole into which many a programmer falls. These optimizations will 99% of times be unnoticable to the average user. Moreover, having a global variable for `bg_element` could make your code 0.00000001% harder to read, and these 'optimizations' people implement end up making the code much harder to debug at the cost of a 0.01ms speed increase.

Again, it's great to worry about performance, but people do tend to go overboard with them to the point where the code is too spread out and incomprehensible. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you so much for your input. But is there a way where I can generate different colors everytime I press the button ?(no repeated colors)